# Highlight javascript inside HTML in Atom editor

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor, highlight

So, I'm new in Atom, and I noticed that when I use `<script>` in HTML, it won't highlight anything, I'd like to know if this is normal, and if it is, how to make Atom highlight JavaScript inside `<script>` tag within HTML?

[image]

Comment: This is really not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. This is a question for forums about that product.

Comment: @charlietfl No, I don't mean the HTML, I mean highlight for javascript as it is, f.e. when I have separate .js file, atom highlights functions like require(), but in here it is just white, this is not about the string in javascript

Comment: Put it in a JavaScript file. Should highlight fine there

Comment: The magic is in the bottom right corner, change auto detect to javascript, please next time don't make @Scott Marcus repeat the words

Answer (score 24):

Go to the settings core tab and uncheck `Use Tree Sitter Parsers` option. Should work without restarting atom.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues. The solution is to install a new theme. 
[Minimal-syntax-dark](https://atom.io/themes/minimal-syntax-dark)